# Using Google OAuth in .NET Core with AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-oauth, asp.net-core-8, aws-load-balancer-controller

We have an IIS server with multiple internal use sites hosted, they all have different subdomains.

AWS load balancer is used with its free SSL certificate, which is then in turn used by all sub domains.

Certificate isn't added via IIS.

I have created an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app (new to web development).
I am now trying to use Google OAuth, but the redirect uri mismatches.

In Google cloud admin panel redirect uri is

```
https://example.maindomain.com
```

But the when the web app requests the uri, it sends is

```
http://example.maindomain.com
```

`Https` is missing.

I think I need to use forward headers, but don't know how.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#require-https help?